# asynchronus operation in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I am using c# language.
Simple WCF service which has method "MethodA" this is doing time consuming heavy job. So for application performance i have created service proxy and choose option "Generate asynchronous operations".
Now at client side i got few more method "BeginMethodA" , "EndMethodA".
Now i called "BegineMethodA" and pass appropriate parameter. 
At client side i have callback method which actually returning me the result for "MethodA". I dont even call "EndMethodA".
What is significant use for "EndMethodA" do i need to call this method to complete the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to call `EndMethodA`. You do this in the async callback to get the actual results (if it has a return value).

Note that there are two ways to make this easier.

1. Just use `Task`. You can actually await across the WCF channel.
2. If you already have Begin/End methods, use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` and `await` *that*.

Both methods are much cleaner from a client perspective and allow you to ignore the ugliness/confusion in the old Begin/End pattern.

Comment: Thanks @BradleyDotNET, before marking as answer i would like to ask one more question. When we use a task factory and start a task. When the result is ready do i need to dispose that task? or task factory will take care for this.

Comment: @Prashant I don't believe you need to dispose the Task object, just `await` it.